# Function to find largest number

Tags: c++, function

I'm learning C++ through Sololearn. Below is a code to find the largest of two numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b){

   if (a > b) {
       return a;
   }

   return b;
} 

int main() {

    cout << max(7, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result - 7

But shouldn't it return b also since there's **return b** in function????

Comment: In C, once you return, you can't go back ... the return a ends the execution of the max function

Comment: The instruction `return` ends the execution of the function: any instruction after a call to `return` is ignored. In your case, if a > b you reach the first return and quit the function ignoring the second return. Otherwise, the first return is not executed which leads to the execution of the second one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only one [`return`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) statement will execute within a function. As soon as the code encounters the first `return` it will immediately leave the function and no further code will execute.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of CoryKramer says it all.
Still, to avoid the confusion you bumped into, I would prefer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b){

   if (a > b) {
       return a;
   }
   else {
       return b;
   }
} 

int main() {

    cout << max(7, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
return a > b ? a : b;
```

The latter line is a so called 'conditional expression' (or 'conditional operator'). If the phrase before the ? is true, it returns the part between the ? and the :, else it returns the part after the :  .

It is explained in detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx).

Comment: ** return a > b ? a : b; **  can you explain this line?

Comment: I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`if (a > b)` (7>4) ==> **Condition becomes True** so `return a` executed and max function return from there only, its not reach to return b, that's why its not execute return b.

Answer (score 2):

Operator return will

> terminate the current function and returns the result of the expression to the caller

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return

After you passed the condition

```
if (a>b)
```

**edited -> thanks to athul**
return will evaluate **a** and put it as result of function.

If a is lesser then b - you will not meet this condition and you will hit

```
return b;
```

To understand it, you may add:

```
cout << max(2, 4) << endl;
cout << max(2, 1) << endl;
```

into the main section.

PS it is better to use at least codeblocks, which is advised in LearnC++ to enter their examples

Comment: @grindah

**After you passed the condition if (a>b) return will evaluate b and put it as result of function**    

  ---->if condition is satisfied return will evaluate **a**  and put it as result of function, right??? not **b**

Answer (score 2):

You can use in **return a > b ? a : b** operator.